# Nyet!: Bonus Card

Tags: nyet

Iello games published a trick-taking game called "Nyet!" The rule book can be found [here](http://www.iellogames.com/downloads/Nyet_EN_rulebook_135x135%20EN.pdf).

The game includes a x2 bonus card in order to offset the imbalance of playing with an odd number of players (since each round is played as teams). On page 11 of the rulebook, it states, "This card *allows* the owner to double her points." Most of the times, this is advantageous. However, depending on the voting phase, tricks taken during the round are potentially worth *negative* points.

**Is the player with the bonus card *required* to use it?

If so, does the bonus card increase the penalty for negative points or decrease the penalty?**

It seems punitive to give the disadvantaged team the bonus card, and then require them to double the loss if the round is worth negative points.

Comment: IF Nyet! is a trick taking game why does it need an explicit trick taking game tag?

Comment: The tags page states "Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question." It facilitates users that have experience with trick taking games to find the question and contribute their knowledge, even if they have not played this specific game.

Comment: The trick taking tag has a total of 20 questions in it including closed questions and is over 6 years old so I am not sure I would call it a useful tag. Wit

Answer (score 1):

The use of the x2 bonus card is mandatory. The first player chooses the player on the smaller team that receives the card and should choose wisely!

This is from [Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2029395/bonus-card-mandatory)

Comment: Where is that information coming from?

Comment: I saw it on boardgamegeek: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2029395/bonus-card-mandatory . To me, it doesn't seem right to be able to ignore the multiplier.

Comment: You should include that in your answer.